# Python format value is returning as null

Tags: python, psycopg2

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simulate_db.py", line 141, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accountsevents (accounts_id, events_id, date_created) VALUES ({0},{1}, TIMEZONE('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));".format(work, eventid))
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2016-10-30 21:14:36.192339, 2016-10-30 21:14:36.192339, 1, 2, f, f, null).
```

I have a simulator dumping info directly into a database. Above the traceback you'll see the number `1`. That is a `print` of the value of `work`, which is a variable in the format method. For some reason it appears as null in the SQL expression. I'm racking my brain trying to understand what's going on here. this is on a remote VPS, but the same simulator file is working fine for me locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll need more information to be sure, but the error says that the `null` value violates a not-null constraint in column `id`, but you're inserting the value of `work` into the `accounts_id` column.

You need to supply a value for the `id` column.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I made the post. It's strange because the id field should be auto incrementing. I shouldn't need to set it. I'll have to dig into the postgres config a bit more I guess.

Comment: Yup the auto increment isn't configured for the id on that table. Weird. Well at least i'm in the right direction. Thanks.